# Text is going off the right-hand side of the page

Tags: paragraphs

I am very new to TeX/LaTeX and have just discovered that when I type

```
\text{blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah}
```

the text seems to automatically go over the right-hand side of the page instead of starting a new line. I know there are ways of doing it manually, but I don't remember having to manually decide when to start new lines constantly when I used this several years ago.

I have used a template and have not changed it much. Here is what I have at the moment:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{framed}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
% \usepackage{cite}
\usepackage{mathrsfs}
\usepackage{array}


%here is me defining some commmands myself
\providecommand{\R}{\mathbb{R}}
\providecommand{\abs}[1]{\lvert#1\rvert}
\providecommand{\chooseq}[2]{\binom{#1}{#2}=\frac{#1!}{#2!\left(#1-#2\right)!}}
\providecommand{\dettwobytwo}[4]{\det \begin{pmatrix}
#1 & #2 \\ 
#3 & #4
\end{pmatrix} = #1\times#4-#2\times#3}
% this first part is the pre-able - it won't appear in the final document,
% the pre-amble is what you set up behind the scenes. 
% You can specify the look of the finished document and what "packages" of 
LaTeX code can be used 

\title{Lecture Notes}
\author{Me}
\begin{document}
\centerline{\Huge Lecture Notes} 
\bigskip \bigskip \bigskip
\centerline{\Large Chapter 1}
\bigskip \bigskip \bigskip
\text{blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah}
\end{document}
```

I have no idea where I am going wrong and would appreciate some assistance.

Comment: Welcome. It is great that you provide a minimal example, but I don't see where it contains the offending `\text` command.

Comment: Why are you using the `\text` command in the text? That is not what that command is for

Comment: After removing the \text command, it now seems fine. I'm not sure why, to be honest.

Comment: The purpose of the amsmath `\text` command is to have regular text in the middle of a displayed equation: `\[a+b=c\text{ because math}\]`.  Because of this use, it doesn't allow line breaks.

Comment: Because it is normal text. If you are new you should probably read a good introduction to latex instead of doing what you are doing here. Noone should be manually makings headlines like that when we have section and friends.

Comment: 'Section and friends'. What do you mean?

Comment: @thewonderfulwizardofoz daleif means things like `\section{}`, `\subsection{}`, `\chapter{}` etc.

Comment: @thewonderfulwizardofoz: `\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{article}
\title{Lecture Notes}
\author{me}
\begin{document}
\maketitle
\section{title of the section}
blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah
\end{document}` might be interesting to have  a look at.